# Allocated memory discrepancy between Memory Analyzer and Task Manager

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, heap-memory, eclipse-memory-analyzer, memoryanalyzer

I want to analyze the memory usage of a pretty huge Java VM process.

One thing I realized when firing up the Eclipse Memory Analysis tool is the huge discrepancy between the alleged allocated memory: Windows Task Manager / CMD Tasklist show around 5,5GB while the Memory Analyzer shows only 1,1GB. What's causing that difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the [Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT)](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) sees and reports is the size of the Java **heap**, i.e., the object graph that’s made up of `Object` instances. What the operating system sees and reports is the size of the region in **RAM** the JVM has requested from the OS to store the Java heap (and its internal data structures) in. This memory is normally not completely filled with *live* Java objects; some objects may already be *dead* (and are not seen be MAT) but have not been collected yet, and the garbage collector itself requires some space to move objects around as well.

I hope this explains the **basics** (there’s lots more details to both JVM and OS memory management).